# Manipulate pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose

I have several monthly reports that each look something like this:

```
data = [['Location 1', 11, 25, 32, 67], ['Location2', 18, 23, 47, 70], ['Location3', 20, 34, 28, 57], ['Location 1', 23, 35, 40, 54]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Location', '# of Apples', '# of Fruits', '# of Carrots', '# of Vegetables'])

Location     # of Apples  # of Fruits   # of Carrots   # of Vegetables
Location 1       11           25             32              67
Location 2       18           23             47              70
Location 3       20           34             28              57
Location 1       23           35             40              54
```

I need to read these reports into one file and create a table that has the location, % of Apple (# of Apples/# of Fruits * 100) and % of Carrots (# of Carrots/# of Vegetables * 100) for each month/report, looking something like this:

```
                      January                   February
Location     % of Apples  % of Carrots   % of Apples  % of Carrots
Location 1      56.7%         59.5%         48.7%          53.8%
Location 2      78.3%         67.1%         73.5%          70.8%
Location 3      58.8%         74.1%         59.2%          72.3%
```

I tried using pd.pivot_table, which gave me the correct format with months going across the top, but I don't know how to calculate the percent values from here.

```
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['# of Apples', '# of Fruits', '# of Carrots', '# of Vegetables'], index=['Location'], columns=['Month'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

I also tried this, which gave me the percent values, but isn't in the correct format.

```
df = df.grouby(['Month', 'Location']).sum()
pivot_table['% of Apples'] = df['# of Apples'] / df['# of Fruit]') * 100
pivot_table['% of Carrots'] = df['# of Carrots'] / df['# of Vegetables']) * 100
```

A note about the months, they are not included in the original data since each report is for one month. When I read the reports in, I add a column that includes the file name. I then replace that with the month.

Thank you!

Comment: As you appear to need the Month in your output, please ensure the Month appears in your input.  For example, it's unclear if you have new columns for each month, or new rows.

Answer (score 0):

My usual approach is just to take it in steps, getting the correct data first, then using pivot to change the layout (de-normalise) at the very end.

I find this useful as the more normalised the data is, the easier it is to re-use in future data-manipulation.

Initial data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  ['Jan', 'Location 1', 11, 25, 32, 67],
  ['Jan', 'Location2',  18, 23, 47, 70],
  ['Jan', 'Location3',  20, 34, 28, 57],
  ['Jan', 'Location 1', 23, 35, 40, 54],
  ['Feb', 'Location 1', 11, 25, 32, 67],
  ['Feb', 'Location2',  18, 23, 47, 70],
  ['Feb', 'Location3',  20, 34, 28, 57],
  ['Feb', 'Location 1', 23, 35, 40, 54],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Month', 'Location', '# of Apples', '# of Fruits', '# of Carrots', '# of Vegetables'])
print(df)
print()
print()
```

Processing and transformation:

```
df = df.groupby(['Month', 'Location'] , as_index=False).sum()
print(df)
print()
print()

df['% Apples']  = df['# of Apples' ] / df['# of Fruits'    ]
df['% Carrots'] = df['# of Carrots'] / df['# of Vegetables']
print(df)
print()
print()


df = df.pivot(index='Location', columns='Month', values=['% Apples', '% Carrots'])
print(df)
print()
print()
```

https://trinket.io/python3/ab8cc6ced4